# Multiple foreach, all sharing the same run counter and avoiding constant checks

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this, *please note that I am free to change my array structure, if you think another format is more flexible*:

```
Array (
  [import_data] => Array (
    [mods] => Array (
      [values] => Array (
      [mod_1_key] => Array (
        [value] => http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/hacking-voice-controllable-devices-with-laser-26.jpg
        [status] => new
      )
      [mod_2_key] => Array (
        [value] => mod_2_value
        [status] => new
      )
      [mod_3_key] => Array (
        [value] => mod_3_value
        [status] => new
      )
        )
      [new] => Array (
        [0] => mod_1_key
        [1] => mod_2_key
        [2] => mod_3_key
      )
    )
    [options] => Array (
      [values] => Array (
        [option_1_key] => Array (
          [value] => option_1_value
          [status] => new
        )
        [option_2_key] => Array (
          [value] => option_2_value
          [status] => new
        )
        [option_3_key] => Array (
          [value] => option_3_value
          [status] => new
        )
      )
      [new] => Array (
        [0] => option_1_key
        [1] => option_2_key
        [2] => option_3_key
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I'm trying to loop through multiple **keys within the array, but only for a total on N times, shared amongst these loops**. My actual, current code is:

```
if( array_key_exists( 'new', $package['options'] ) ) {
    foreach( $package['new'] as $new_option_key ) {
        //do something with it.
    }
}

if( array_key_exists( 'changed', $package['options'] ) ) {
    foreach( $package['changed'] as $changed_option_key ) {
        //do something with it.
    }
}
```

So, I would want to perform these operations for the keys `new` and `changed` only for these N times. That is to say, if my N is 6, then each loop should only run 3 times.

If I were to introduce a `$run_counter` and increase it every time I loop, then check it in the loop every time, it works - I tried it, but the code looks like total garbage. As such my question is not only about how can I do something, but how can I do it gracefully?

Comment: edit: formatted array spacings

Comment: Have you tried `foreach(array_slice($package["new"],0,$N/2,TRUE) as $key)` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes! That's the solution I ended up on and although it's Big(O), I think it's the only way. If you post your solution as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for a clean and nice looking code I would suggest trying

```
foreach(array_slice($package["new"], 0, $N / 2, TRUE) as $key)
....
foreach(array_slice($package["changed"], 0, $N / 2, TRUE) as $key)
....
```

PHP uses `copy-on-write` technique so the array that is being returned by `array_slice()` will internally contain just references to the original values in the original array (do not mix these "internal references" with the real `&$x` variable references).

Comment: Yes! I was experimenting with `&` but I just read that, fortunately, PHP uses references and so, optimization is very good. I've tested memory management / performance with `array_slice` on an array of 50k and under *very* heavy load and it's as fast as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a regular `for` loop then?

```
$max_iteration = 3;
if( array_key_exists( 'new', $package['options'] ) ) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $max_iteration; $i++) {
        $new = $package['new'][$i];
        //do something with it.
    }
}

if( array_key_exists( 'changed', $package['options'] ) ) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $max_iteration; $i++) {
        $changed = $package['changed'][$i];
        //do something with it.
    }
}
```